# How to Split string but keep delimiter at the start

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I was wondering how to Split a string in C# but keeping the delimiters at the start of each substring.

Example:

Input: `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`

Delimiter: `','`

Output: `{'1', ',2', ',3', ',4', ',5', ',6'}`

At the moment I only know to keep the delimiter at the end of each substring using Regex.Split from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788033/8554358).

```
 String text = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
 var split = Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=,)");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of lookbehind you need to use a lookahead for splitting:

```
(?=,)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G3imyJ/1)

What you want is splitting on a position when you have comma at next position that makes it a **lookahead assertion**. On the other hand a lookbehind assertion will split when we have comma at previous position thus splitting after comma not before it.

**Code:**

```
String text = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var split = Regex.Split(text, @"(?=,)");
//=> ["1", ",2", ",3", ",4", ",5", ",6"]
```